# Countability of all finite strings over an alphabet

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the set of all finite strings over the alphabet $\{01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,/\}$ countable?

If it is, wouldn't the set of positive rationals also be countable? Why is the above set countable?

Answer (score 0):

you can express it as a countable union of countable sets, and thus it is countable. The set of positive rationals (and also that of all rationals) is indeed countable, so there is not (alluded) contradiction or problem here.